# Save images in a certain folder when taking picture mkdirs() android/java

Tags: java, android

I have a function that takes a picture and is saves it in a folder that the app makes itself. However, when I use my function to select an image, the folder doesn't show up as one of the options. Is there any fix or anything wrong with the code? Is there a certain way to call the folder that I have saved it in so that the app only allows images to be selected from there?

Save image to folder:

```
private void saveImageToFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String directoryName = "TTS";
        String filename = "imagefortranslation" + 1;
        
        File directory = new File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), directoryName);

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs(); // Creates the directory if it doesn't exist
        }

        File file = new File(directory, filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(requireActivity().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image saved to " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Select image:

```
private void pickImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}
```

Comment: "Is there a certain way to call the folder that I have saved it in so that the app only allows images to be selected from there?" -- do not use `ACTION_PICK`. Implement your own image-selection logic, either from scratch or using a library.